# LaTeX Code from Kable showing up in R markdown PDF?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am trying to put a table in my R-markdown report and I like the table that this produces but the laTeX code is showing up in the report. What am I doing wrong? Please see picture and code for reference. I am very new at LaTeX and markdown and really have no idea what I'm doing haha. The data is blacked out in the image for security reasons. Thank you!

[PDF output with issues :( (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCbVy.png)

````
---
title: "Deal Fees by Client Ownership 2008-2018"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{booktabs}
    - \usepackage{caption}
---
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(xtable)
library(kableExtra)
```
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, comment=NA, results = 'asis'}


kable(df, format = "latex", caption = "Fee variances ($ millions)", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>% 
  group_rows("Average", 1, 4) %>% 
  group_rows("Median", 5, 8)

```
````

Answer (score 5):

You have a $ in your caption. You need to escape that.

```
caption = "Fee variances (\\$ millions)"
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question; however, I ran into this issue and just found out that the reason was that my code chunk name contained an underscore: `csd_results`.   I changed the underscore to a dash `-` and it fixed the problem. Other special characters may cause the problem as well.